# Help with finding $\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(x)\log(x^2+1)}{x(x^2+1)}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to evaluate $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(x)\log(x^2+1)}{x(x^2+1)}$$ I have tried differentiating under the integral sign, with different parameters, as well as contour integration, but I have not succeeded with neither of them. Wolfram Alpha gives a numerical value $\approx 0.754694$, but I suspect that there is a more exact answer.

I would be very glad to get some hints on how to solve it.

Comment: This is [solved here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128300). See the middle of the accepted answer there "For the integral let $F(a) =\ldots$"

Comment: Exact value: $\frac{1}{2} \ln ^2(2) \pi$